# Can i change/add logo in magento login page and backend page ? How?

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, login

I have to change logo for existing magento login page and backend page with new one. Is there any function to change ?

Here is login page image and backend page image :

[image: Backend]
[image]

Comment: You want to change new logo in backend right

Comment: Yes existing is old one i want to replace with new one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic knowledge about the default logos:**
At first you have to know that there is not only one logo to replace in your store. By default Magento makes use of these 3 logos:
**Default Magento Header Logo**
The logo in the header section of your store frontend
Default location: skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/images/logo.gif
**Default Magento Email Logo**
The logo in all transactional emails
Default location: skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/images/logo_email.gif
**Default Magento Print Logo**
The logo in all printable documents like invoices and packing slips
Default location: skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/images/logo_print.gif
How to replace all logos in your Magento store
The easiest and fastest way to change all 3 default Magento logos is to replace the logos on your FTP server. To do that just login to your server using FTP and navigate to this folder: skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME. There you find the following files:

- logo.gif
- logo_email.gif
- logo_print.gif

You can now replace the default logos by uploading your own logos with the same file names. Done! Now you see your own company logo on all mentioned places. OK, so far so good. But what to do if you don’t want to use a GIF but a PNG ot JPG? No problem!
You can easily define the the logos for each of the 3 logos in your Magento backend.
**Change Header Logo**

1. Upload your own logo with your custom filename and extension to your FTP serverskin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME.
2. In your Magento backend navigate to: System > Configuration > Design
3. In the Header section you find all settings for the logo in your Magento store frontend.
4. In the field Logo Image Src you can now replace images/logo.gif with your own filename like images/mylogo.png.
5. Furthermore you can also define the alt tag of your logo image in the field Logo Image Alt.

**Change Email Logo**

1. In your Magento backend navigate to: System > Configuration > Design
2. In the Transactional Emails section you find all settings for the logo in your Magento Emails.
3. Here you can easily upload your Email Logo in the field Logo Image.
4. Furthermore you can also define the alt tag of your logo image in the field Logo Image Alt.

**Change Print Logo**

1. In your Magento backend navigate to: System > Configuration > Sales
2. In the Invoice and Packing Slip Design section you find all settings for the logo in your printable documents.
3. Here you can easily upload your Email Logo in the field Logo for PDF Print-outs (200×50) and Logo for HTML Print View.

﻿

Comment: Did not explain the backend logo.

Answer (score 2):

Login page logo is a background element in css file of your theme so this is the quickest way if you dont want to edit css file.
To change logo in Login page, you need to upload and replace login_logo.gift in `adminhtml/default/default/images/login_logo.gift`

For backend page, you can either upload/replace `/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/logo.gif` or upload newlogo.gif and change the following line in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml`

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif')
```

to

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/newlogo.gif')
```

Hope this helps!

Reference source: http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-change-default-magento-logo-in-backend-and-frontend

Comment: This solution gets overwritten on update, so it's not a recommended method. Best way is to create a custom module as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419081/how-can-i-change-logo-of-magento-in-backend.

Answer (score 1):

Upload new logo in your skin folder then change image name here

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.header.phtml




<a href="<?php echo $this->getHomeLink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo
$this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Magento Logo') ?>"
class="logo"/></a>
```

Comment: Great, thanks but still not changing in login page!

Comment: @BishalNeupane for login page upload new logo in your skin folder with name login_logo.gif

Comment: skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css change .login-container(background:url(enter url path))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update/change logo from Magento backend (without using FTP) then you can do the following:

- Login to your Magento admin
- Edit any static block (`CMS -> Static Blocks`)
- There you will see `Insert Image` button. Click on it.
  [image]
- Upload your logo image there. Suppose, your logo name is `logo.png`. Then, the image path will be `http://your-website.com/media/wysiwyg/logo.png`
- Now, go to `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Header`
- Update `Logo Image Src` to `../../../../../media/wysiwyg/logo.png`. This has to be done because by default Magento fetches image from `skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/images` directory.
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple to change the magento backend logo.

1. right click on the magento backend logo.
2. click on ' copy image address'
3. past it int he browser. you will get the exact logo address in the address bas.
4. follow the path in file zilla and upload your logo through filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here give a proper solution. They either miss the point completely (the question is about the logos in the backend, not frontend) or they offer temporary solutions that only work until Magento is updated, at which point the custom files are overwitten and you are back to square one.

The recommended method is to create a custom module, as explained in the accepted solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419081/how-can-i-change-logo-of-magento-in-backend